# Python file not saving high score

Tags: python

I am currently trying to make a number guessing game to practice my coding. Everything works except for the fact it is not saving my high score when I restart the game, any suggestions?

```
print('Can you guess the number on the first try (hint: its inbetween 1-100)?')

import random
randomNum = random.randint(0,100)

userNum = 0
guesses = 0
userHigh = 0

gFile = open("score.txt", "r") #tells the score
gFile.read()
int(guesses)
print("the previous high score was", userHigh)
gFile.close()


while randomNum != userNum:
    try:

        userNum=int(input("What is your guess?: "))
        if randomNum>userNum:
            print('Higher')
        elif randomNum<userNum:
            print('Lower')

    except:
        print("please entera numeric value")
    else:
            guesses+=1

print("You win! The number was", randomNum)
print("You took {} guesses!".format(guesses))

gFile = open("score.txt", "w")
gFile.write(str(guesses))
gFile.close()
```

Comment: There are a number of errors in your script, `guesses` and `userHigh` are never updated (the statement `int(guesses)` does nothing in the end...).

Comment: The "high score" is saved to the file (try opening it in a text file) but you don't retrieve the value when you rerun the script.

Comment: Which part of the code isn't working? You should be able to narrow it down. e.g. does the score get written to the text file? If you manually put a number in score.txt does it get printed out? etc.

Answer (score 1):

you never update the userHigh var, try this:

```
userNum = 0
guesses = 0
userHigh = 0

gFile = open("score.txt", "r") #tells the score
h = gFile.read()
if h is not None:
   userHigh = h #update UserHigh
int(guesses)
print("the previous high score was", userHigh)
gFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

> `print("the previous high score was", userHigh)`

Of course you are getting always '0', because you aren't storing the value on the variable userHigh.
When you run the function gFile.read(), you have to store the value on the userHigh var, like this:

```
userHigh = gFile.read()
```

If you don't do that, you are just executing the function.
Also I must add that the program isn't storing the high score, is just storing whatever score.
For storing only the high score you must do this:

```
if userHigh < guesses:
    gFile = open("score.txt", w)
    gFile.write(str(guesses))
    gFile.close()
```